# What to do when GParted tells me: ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I bought a Seagate Expansion 1TB Drive few month's ago. It was working smooth until 3 to 4 days ago, when this problem struck me.

I plugged it to my laptop in Windows 7 (I have Dual Boot, Ubuntu 12.10 and Win 7 as well), the drive got mounted but when I tried to open folders present in it, the window used to show 'not responding' message (same as a window hang's in Window's OS).

Then I tried to find the problem using Gparted, and Gparted showed me an this warning,

[image: screenshot]

also this,

[image: screenshot]

I also tried to run ntfsfix command, and following was  the output,

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for satwik:
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
satwik@satwik-HP-ProBook-4430s:~$
```

Please Help Me Out! I have already lost my previous 500GB Drive.

Comment: I think you need to run chkdsk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do as it says and run chkdsk from windows.  Also it looks like you have some bad sectors.  Check `dmesg` for more detailed errors, and also check the SMART status of the drive in the disk utility.